# How to push data into an Observable<any[]> whenever another observable emits?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

### What I intend to accomplish

I want to be able to push some data into an observable when another observable emits. The second observable contains an iterable because I need a collection of pushed elements to be read by a template with *ngFor (using the async pipe).

### My code

#### component:

```
eventEmitter: Observable<any>;
newChannelsIncluded: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    // create an observable that contains an iterable
    this.newChannelsIncluded = Observable.from([]);

    // create an emitter to grab the data I will push to the iterable
    this.eventEmitter = Observable.fromEvent(
        document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropdown'), 'click');

    // push the data into the iterable inside the observable
    this.eventEmitter
        .subscribe( e => {             
            this.newChannelsIncluded
                .pushIntoTheIterableInsideTheObservable(e.target.value);
        });
}
```

#### template:

```
<div *ngFor="let channel of newChannelsIncluded | async" >
    <span>{{channel}}</span>
    <span (click)="removeChannel($event)"</span>
</div>
```

### The specific place I'm stuck at

What the question title says, how to push to the iterable inside the second observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [`scan`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md)

```
this.newChannelsIncluded = this.eventEmitter.scan((acc, x) => {
  acc.push(x);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zLzzv7j4/

However, if you also want to remove the items later then you should maintain this list of channels in a behavior subject.

```
this.newChannelsIncluded = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>();
this.eventEmitter.subscribe(newChannel => {
  let channels = this.newChannelsIncluded.value;
  channels.push(newChannel);
  this.newChannelsIncluded.next(channels );
});
```

At this point, since you are using Angular, I would also recommend encapsulating this list of channels in a service which hides the behavior subject from the world.